# MySQL not accepting password, responds with using password: NO

Tags: mysql

I'm telling mysql to prompt for a password but it won't acknowledge it:

```
mysql -h xxxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root –p
```

response: Access denied for user 'root@%'@'10.10.1.1' (using password: NO)

Even when I explicitly pass the password in the connection string I get the same response:

```
mysql -h xxxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root –pMyPassword
```

response: Access denied for user 'root@%'@'10.10.1.1' (using password: NO)

What is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong character in front of `p`, try to delete that character and replace it with `-`, you can also try using following `--password=XXX`, and lastly `-P 3306` isn't needed unless you're using NON-standard port.

Comment: You just gotta hate those annoying unicode hyphens.

Comment: heh, just don't copy and paste))

Comment: ...How did it even occur to you to check this? +1 for (I assume) looking at the bytecode of his command line.

Comment: @parthianshot sorry to disappoint you, but I didn't look at bytecode to see it(. I just copy & paste it to my terminal, removed `-h` and hit `enter`, my answer was right there as it threats that part as name for database therefore no `-p`.

Comment: @alexus Aww... Well, still solid debugging in any case.

Comment: Good catch. If you look closely the dashes are not the same size. :P

Comment: This is one of the reasons why my documentations are always plain text files. Microsoft Word has done too much damage to my command lines, same goes for Evernote. Sometimes you want a tool that just saves things *exactly* as you pasted it.